# Calculate the height in a div with text

Tags: jquery

How I can calculate the heigth or count of words that the text of  a div have inside with jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use height(), try this

```
var height = $("div").height();
```

O and counting words would be something like

```
var words = $('div').text().split(' ').length;
```

Comment: How I cant take the real height because in different monitors take different value..